# Where to get Oracle SERVICE_NAME?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I just installed Oracle database 10g free version for students on my Windows XP. I am confused how to know the SERVICE_NAME? Am running it at my localhost 127.0.0.1, with username SYSTEM. May I know where can I get to know the SERVICE_NAME?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is normally XE for the free version. ORCL is another typical value.

Once logged in, it can be determined from

```
select sys_context('USERENV','SERVICE_NAME') from dual
```

If you need to know it so that you can log in, look for a file called TNSNAMES.ORA in
$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/network/admin and the service name will probably be in the connection string.

Answer (score 4):

Since its windows, you can go to control panel - administrative tools - services : (switch to classic mode in control panel if you do not see admin tools). Once there you will have a service by the  name "Oracle service_". The  is your service name.

Comment: That's simply wrong. He is asking about Oracle services, not windows services. These are two very different things.

Comment: Do you realize what you are talking abt ? :). I am nt talking abt windows services. In windows, oracle will start a service with the name pattern "OracleService<ORCL_SERV_NAME>". I suggest you take time to understand before you comment.

Comment: then you shouldn't use the term service_name. This has a very specific meaning in oracle.